# How to refesh your cursor adapter, when the database has changed?

Tags: android, adapter

for example, when i add a row to the database, i run the ff. code,

```
            Cursor crs = adapterToRefresh.getCursor();
            crs.close();
            crs = this.dbImmunization.queryAll();
            this.startManagingCursor(crs);
            crs.moveToFirst();
            adapterToRefresh.changeCursor(crs);
            adapterToRefresh.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

where crs, is the cursor retrieve within the cursor adapter.

so far, this implementation gives me an error of CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Help anyone!

Answer (score 0):

First use the sqlite browser to see the tables and rows if created properly. second when you are traversing the database how you are going to the end row. may be there is the problem. It will be clearer only when u show your logcat output.

Comment: adapterToRefresh.getCursor().requery();
    adapterToRefresh.notifyDataSetChanged();, I use these code, but none work.:(

Answer (score 0):

You have called the startManagingCursor(cursor), therefore you don't need to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). Instead, call cursor.requery() when you need to refresh its query and fetched data.